# Arrayformula multiply values and sum results in one row per month

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs

I'm trying to reduce steps when having to multiply and sum using ArrayFormula.

In a total row, I have this formula (Row 38):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN($F$1:$Q$1),SUMIF(IF(ROW(E27:E35),COLUMN($4:$4)),COLUMN($4:$4),F27:Q35)))
```

But it requires an intermediate calculation (Row 27):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(F5:Q12*F16:Q23)
```

Can I somehow eliminate it? Can I use SUMIFS to do it to sum on multiple criteria?

Here is the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TXx4wXM98HjhPHiOMotPrvxLBj6LrwYXmOazqdd8J08/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: Try `=MMULT({1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},ARRAYFORMULA(F5:Q12*F16:Q23))`.

Comment: So you basically want to combine the two above formulas right?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf, YES!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my question was:

```
=MMULT({1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},ARRAYFORMULA(F5:Q12*F16:Q23))
```

Comment: Hi ! If you have additional questions please, ask them in a new post following [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Also, could you edit your answer so that it exactly includes @Kpym solution? Thanks ! :D